# If array values match each other, then shuffle again

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form where users can input numbers in 7 different fields and then I use

```
shuffle($_POST);
```

to mix up the numbers and then display them against the numbers they in-putted originally, so the output looks like this:

```
1 1
2 4
3 6
4 2
5 7
6 3
7 5
```

Here is the code I'm using.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
$array = implode("",$_POST);
shuffle($_POST);
}
?>
<div class="box"><?php echo $array[0]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[0]; ?></div><br>
<div class="box"><?php echo $array[1]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[1]; ?></div><br>
<div class="box"><?php echo $array[2]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[2]; ?></div><br>
<div class="box"><?php echo $array[3]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[3]; ?></div><br>
<div class="box"><?php echo $array[4]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[4]; ?></div><br>
<div class="box"><?php echo $array[5]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[5]; ?></div><br>
<div class="box"><?php echo $array[6]; ?> <?php echo $_POST[6]; ?></div><br>
```

How do I check two arrays values against each other to make sure they don't match. If they do match then I would like to use shuffle() again untill not one of them match. I will probably use an if else statement to run the code again until the numbers don't match but not sure how to go about it.

Comment: In your output example there are numbers in the second column that do not exist in the first one. is this right ?

Comment: I accidentally used another example, fixed it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `array_intersect_assoc($array,$_POST);` in while loop until it returns null array, shuffle!

using `array_intersect_assoc()`:

```
$array = $_POST;
do {
    shuffle($_POST);

} while ((count(array_intersect_assoc($array, $_POST))) !=0);
```

Comment: Both of them don't work for me. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The numbers still match up sometimes

Comment: I have made a small change. It was the variable mistake I made. If the problem still persists, please post the code you tried let me check that out

Comment: It was actually my mistake, so the code before worked fine using aray_intersect_assoc()! My problem was that my keys were named nothing else so I forgot to reset them

Comment: Glad that I helped you!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper function to test if the arrays have matches, and shuffle until there are no matches left.

```
function has_same_matches($arr1, $arr2) {
    for($i=0, $sz = count($arr1); $i < $sz; ++$i) {
        if ($arr1[$i] == $arr2[$i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
$shuffled = $array;

while(has_same_matches($array, $shuffled)) {
    shuffle($shuffled);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use $_POST like that directly, but anyway I think this soultion should work for you.
Also please note that, shuffle() does not preserve the array keys.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
    $init_array = $_POST;
    $array = implode("",$_POST); //user input
    shuffle($_POST);
    $after_shuffle = $_POST;
    while($init_array == $after_shuffle){
       shuffle($_POST);
    }
    $final_array = $_POST; //array with unmatched values
 }
```

Comment: I tried this and I changed the echo code as well but it didn't work.     <div class="box"><?php echo $array[1]; ?> <?php echo $final_array[1]; ?></div><br> - They still match sometimes